# Проверка на русский язык php

Tags: php

Есть задачка на php.

На сайте необходимо развернуть форму для отправки на почту

Вопрос вот в чем, как на этом языке сделать проверку текста, чтобы если вдруг есть иностранный текст появлялась уведомление, мол "пиши по человечески"?

Причин рассказать не могу, чтоб не смеялись, но очень буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Что значит "на русский язык". Чтобы в тексте были только символы кириллицы? Или же нужно реальную проверку что это русский язык, а не какой-то другой?

Comment: `preg_match()` и регулярка по типу `/[a-z]/i` вам в помощь.

Comment: Если простыми словами, то: "привет" - можно, "hello" - нельзя. Вариант только с кириллицей подойдет

Comment: *"preg_match() и регулярка по типу /[a-z]/i вам в помощь."*
А как это выглядит в коде? Я просто в этом языке вообще 0...
Если не сложно, можете написать пример?

Comment: @BogdanChyornyy, предположим, что значение поля формы у вас хранится в переменной `$value`, тогда `preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $value)` вернет вам 1 если найден латинский символ, 0 если нет (или false, если ошибка).

Answer (score -3):

Можно использовать такую функцию, несколько букв я показал для примера, остальные допишите сами.

```
<?php
function Letter_Replase(){
        global $l_r;
        $_0     = str_replace("ü","у", $l_r);
        $_1     = str_replace("Ü","У", $_0);
        $_2     = str_replace("ö","о", $_1);
        $_3     = str_replace("Ö","O", $_2);
        $_4     = str_replace("ğ","г", $_3);
        $_5     = str_replace("Ğ","Г", $_4);
        $_6     = str_replace("ə","e", $_5);
        $_7     = str_replace("Ə","E", $_6);
        $_8     = str_replace("ı","и", $_7);
        $_9     = str_replace("I","И", $_8);
        $_10    = str_replace("ç","ч", $_9);
        $_11    = str_replace("Ç","Ч", $_10);
        $_12    = str_replace("ş","ш", $_11);
        $_13    = str_replace("Ş","Ш", $_12);
        $_14    = str_replace("'","", $_13);
        $_15    = str_replace(",","", $_14);
        $_16    = str_replace('"',"", $_15);
        $_17    = str_replace('`',"", $_16);
        $_18    = str_replace('-',"", $_17);
        $_19    = str_replace('--',"", $_18);
        $_20    = str_replace('---',"", $_19);
        $_21    = str_replace(':',"", $_20);
        $_22    = str_replace('   ',"-", $_21);
        $_23    = str_replace(';',"-", $_22);
        $_24    = str_replace('_',"", $_23);
        $_25    = str_replace('“',"", $_24);
        $_26    = str_replace('”',"", $_25);
        $_27    = str_replace('!',"", $_26);
        $_28    = str_replace('?',"", $_27);
        $_29    = str_replace('@',"", $_28);
        $_30    = str_replace('$',"", $_29);
        $_31    = str_replace('%',"", $_30);
        $_32    = str_replace('^',"", $_31);
        $_33    = str_replace('&',"", $_32);
        $_34    = str_replace('*',"", $_33);
        $_35    = str_replace('=',"", $_34);
        $_36    = str_replace('+',"", $_35);
        $_37    = str_replace('/',"", $_36);
        $_38    = str_replace("\/","", $_37);
        $_39    = str_replace('|',"", $_38);
        $_40    = str_replace('[',"", $_39);
        $_41    = str_replace(']',"", $_40);
        $_42    = str_replace('>',"", $_41);
        $_43    = str_replace('<',"", $_42);
        $_44    = preg_replace('/{}[(][)][.]/', '', $_43);
        echo mb_strtolower($_44);
    }
?>
```